# Wordpress is redirecting the main page from http to https automatically

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect

We are importing a wordpress website to a local apache server, in windows, and we copied all the code in a directory in htdocs.

The problem is when we try to launch the website in the browser, it is always redirected to https.

We have configured the http.conf in order to do localhost point to the root directory of the website. But when we access to http://localhost in browser always is converted to https://localhost

When we analyze in Chrome the network tab information in the developer settings, we see a redirection and that redirection is done by Wordpress:

[Image of Http to https Redirection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuYhw.png)

[Image of Redirected by wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvoyW.png)

We can't neither access to the admin page and we don't know if is a default plugin or a database configuration the reason of the redirection, but we are lost. (we have desactivated the apache ssl module and the redirections in htaccess)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the value of 'siteurl' and 'home' in the wp_options table of the database? Probably there you have the url defined with https and that is why it is redirecting. You can access with phpmyadmin and change it directly, or launch the query from the console.

If it wasn't the first option, an SSL enable plugin may be doing the job, try disabling all plugins (you can rename the plugin root folder temporarily while testing to disable it)

Comment: yeah, you covered the possible scenarios, also maybe check apache config too @amanbur  perhaps; like if its redirecting port 80 to 443.

Comment: Hi, effectively, a plugin was the problem, we have desactivated it and no more problems Thank you!!